# Opening a file from a path relative to the binary when running from a different directory

Tags: bash, path, c

Lets say I have a binary, `sayhello` along with a text file `hello.txt` in the directory `/path/to/hello/`. The binary reads the text file and outputs its contents to `stdout`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[14];
    FILE* file = fopen("/path/to/hello/hello.txt", "r");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file);
    puts(buffer);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

`[/path/to/hello/] $ ./sayhello          Hello, world!`

I can run `sayhello` from anywhere, if I add its directory to `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/hello/
[/other/path/] $ sayhello          Hello, world!
```

I know I can use `fopen` with a relative path as well: `FILE* file = fopen("hello.txt", "r");` However, if I did this, I would always have to run `sayhello` from the directory that contains the text file (and in my case, the binary as well.) I would like `fopen` to open the file from a path that's relative to the binary itself, not the directory where I happen to run it from. This would let me move the directory with the files somewhere else and just modify my `PATH` accordingly, leaving the binary itself unmodified. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I couldn't find that myself

Comment: Using `XDG_DATA_HOME` and `XDG_DATA_DIRS` rather than things being relative to the program image file is an approach that you might want to consider.